# NuGet caused a handful of reference conflicts after updating the packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, tfs, nuget

I've currently been engaged in a ASP.NET MVC 4 project. In order to take advantage of the new Identity Model in the version 5, I updated the project using NuGet and made some changed accordingly. It worked fine with warnings of reference conflicts though.

However, when I deployed it to Windows Azure, it stopped working. In detail, I could access a HTML file in the virtual directory, which wouldn't be allowed normally according to the rules, and all the controllers are ignored and inaccessible (404) somehow.

I even logged in to the server, checked and disassembled the DLLs, only to find that there were ambiguous matches. So I took a even closer look at the reference conflicts and got shocked - there were enormous of them. Even mscorlib and System.Web were involved. The issue still exists after I set "Copy Local" of all the references to true.

As you can see, it's not that easy to generate redirect binding for all of them. I'm wondering there must be some difference between the referencing on the server and locally but cannot figure it out.

Does anyone have a solution? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of NuGet is installed on your server? There have been some binding-redirect bugs that are fixed in latest version of NuGet.

Could you please install the latest NuGet from http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget and see if your issue still exists? Thanks.

Comment: Actually it was the time that I decided to update the project that I updated my NuGet software to the latest version. Thx all the same. :)